# how to remove space in a string in C?

Tags: c, string, space

I'm trying the code below but get a wrong output. For example I type "a b c" and I want the result to be "abc", but the result is a chinese character.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
/* function prototype */
char *sweepSpace(char *sentence);
int main()
{
    char str[80];
    printf("Enter a string: ");//enter a string for example "a b c'
    gets(str);
    printf("Result: %s  ", sweepSpace(str));//should print "abc"here 
    return 0;
}
char *sweepSpace(char *setence)
{
    char b[80];     
    int i = 0;
    while (*setence != NULL)
    {
        //if not reach the end
        if (!isspace(*setence))
        {
            //if not a space
            b[i] = *setence;//assign setence to b
            i++;//increment 
        }
        setence++;//pointer increment
    }
    b[i]= "\0";

    return b;//return b to print
}
```

Comment: b[i]= "\0" - change it to b[i]= '\0'; (use single quote)

Comment: `*setence != NULL`, this doesn't seem correct at first sight. `NULL` is usually used to specify memory address. You should use `'\0'`

Comment: Do I see a `gets` there! Please **never** use `gets`. It's deprecated and unsafe.

Comment: In while loop comparison between character and NULL pointer ,so remove the "*" , So it compares the address with NULL pointer ,So warning message will be omitted .for example while ( setence != NULL )

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a local array variable (`b`), which invokes undefined behavior when it's accessed in `main()`.

Don't do this.

Copy the new string back before the function ends:

```
strcpy(setence, b);
```

Some more notes:

1. It's spelled `sentence`.
2. Check against `'\0'`, not `NULL`.
3. Cast to `unsigned int` when using `isspace()`.
4. The terminator is `'\0'`, not `"\0"`.

Comment: Did you mean `"\0"` instead of `"}"`

Answer (score 1):

`b` is scoped in function. Copy back the result to your original pointer.

Something like:

`strcpy(setence, b);`

Answer (score 0):

With this code you are trying to return `b`, which is defined on `stack`. Once you are out of scope it will not reflect in `main`.

```
char b[80];
..
..
return b;//return b to print
```

Instead, you return `new_b`.

```
char* new_b = (char*)malloc(strlen(b)+1);
strncpy(new_b,b,strlen(b)+1);
return new_b;//return b to print
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return an automatic array in `C`. When the function `sweepSpace` returns, the array `b` goes out of scope (it's allocated on the stack) and you return the address of a memory location to `main` which is no longer available. This would cause undefined behaviour and likely result in segfault. Also, never use `gets`. It does not check the bound of the buffer it writes into and can overrun the buffer if the input string is too large. Use `fgets` instead. This would again lead to error. Here's what I suggest.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>        // for prototype of isspace
#include <stdlib.h>       // for prototype of malloc

char *sweepSpace(char *sentence);

int main(void)     // parameter list should contain void explicitly
{
    char str[80];  
    printf("Enter a string: "); //enter a string for example "a b c'
    fgets(str, 80, stdin);  // read at most 79 chars. add null byte at the end
    char *new_sentence = sweepSpace(str);
    if(new_sentence) {
        printf("Result: %s  ", new_sentence); //should print "abc" here
        free(new_sentence);
        new_sentence = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}

char *sweepSpace(char *sentence)
{
    char *b = malloc(1 + strlen(sentence)); // +1 for the null byte
    if(b == NULL) {
        printf("Not enough memory");
        return NULL;
    }     
    int i = 0;
    while(*sentence != '\0')  // compare with null byte, not NULL pointer  
    {
        //if not reach the end
        if (!isspace(*sentence))
        {
            // if not a space

            b[i] = *sentence; //assign sentence to b
            i++;  //increment 
        }
        sentence++; //pointer increment
    }
    b[i]= '\0';   // "\0" is a string literal, not a character.
    return b;  //return b to print
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *a="hello world";
int i;
int w=strlen(a);
for(i=0; i<=w; i++) {
if(*(a+i)==' ') { 
for(j=i;j<=w-1;j++) {
*(a+i)=*(a+1);
} }
}

/* if there is a space, push all next character one byte back */
```

this should work.